# SQL Server : returning text only in the brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching, database-normalization

I have text stored in column; in hundreds of rows. The text is `VARCHAR` and anywhere from 500-5000 characters. I want to return only the numbers between 2 brackets.

So here's an example

```
abcd(22135)  
hhgygas(52142)dijijijs  
whatisthis(33234) i have no idea (22342)
```

And the result should be

```
22135  
52142  
33234  
22342
```

Comment: when do you have 3 rows of sample data and 4 rows of expected result? Do you expect a pivot too? If so, I'd look into a splitter. Also, if this can be simplified as "return only the digits" then that would be easier too...

Comment: You could do a table valued function.  Load it with an outer loop for each row and an inner loop for each occurance of brackets.

Comment: Why tag [database-normalization]?

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use a substring function to extract only the numbers.  Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(max);
SET @x = 'lmfasdfa(1234567)asdfasdfaff'


SELECT
    SubString(@x,CHARINDEX('(',@x)+1,CHARINDEX(')',@x)-CHARINDEX('(',@x)-1) AS numbers1
```

output looks like:

```
1234567
```

Comment: Well, this solution is great BUT the problem is that i have 100's of rows in a table, containing thousands of characters in every field. Table name: dev_account Field: dev_text. The table dev_account has 500+ rows

Comment: Will the data you want to extract always be between two parentheses? If it will then you just swap out @X with dev_text and then select from the dev_account table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an UDF and a CROSS APPLY to get all values.

> ```
> create table tbl (txt varchar(max));
> insert into tbl values
> ('abcd(22135)'), 
> ('hhgygas(52142)dijijijs'),
> ('whatisthis(33234) i have no idea (22342)');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> create function dbo.getValues(@txt varchar(max)) 
> returns @t table
> (val varchar(20))
> as
> begin
>     declare @p1 int, @p2 int;
>     set @p1 = 0;
>     set @p2 = 0;
>
>     while charindex('(', @txt, @p2) <> 0
>     begin
>         set @p1 = charindex('(', @txt, @p2);
>         if @p1 = 0 return;
>         set @p2 = charindex(')', @txt, @p1);
>         if @p2 = 0 return;
>         insert into @t values(substring(@txt, @p1 + 1, @p2 - @p1 - 1));
>     end
>
>     return;
> end
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select f.val
> from   tbl
> cross apply dbo.getValues(tbl.txt) f
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | val   |
> | :---- |
> | 22135 |
> | 52142 |
> | 33234 |
> | 22342 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fb5c4c2c661a17159cb7b0657d1c2dc)*

Comment: This is a great solution, however, when i run it against the actual Table, i get this.  
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: How many digits have your numbers? Change varchar(20) by varchar(100)

Comment: maximum of 5. maybe i am doing something wrong. Leme re-try and get back with you. Thank you

Comment: Ok, i increased the VARCHAR(20) with VARCHAR(1000) and its WORKING. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of [ngrams2b](https://github.com/AlanBurstein/SQL-Library/blob/master/dbo.NGrams2B.sql) and you can do this:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @table TABLE (someid int identity, col1 varchar(max));
INSERT @table VALUES
('abcd(22135)'),
('hhgygas(52142)dijijijs'),
('whatisthis(33234) i have no idea (22342)'),
('nothing to see here');

-- Solution    
SELECT 
  t.someid,
  numbers = 
    substring(t.col1, position+1,nullif(charindex(')', t.col1, position+1),0)-position-1)
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY dbo.ngrams2b(t.col1,1)
WHERE token = '(';
```

**Results**

```
someid      numbers
----------- --------
1           22135
2           52142
3           33234
3           22342
```